# R barplot function fix column width and name

Tags: r, plot, width, bar-chart

I have worked on creating barplot for some data set with using split and table function. Even though is gives a barplot at the end of process, I couldn't change bar size and its name.

My data set name is AKP.Slogans and it has two columns that are tweet_created_at (POSIXct, format: "2015-05-08 00:07:58") and hashtag_text (chr"ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar").

Sample of data set:

```
tweet_created_at    hashtag_text 
5/8/2015 0:07   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 2:50   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 2:53   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar,pinokyokemal
5/8/2015 0:11   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:11   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 2:53   bingolunkararibuyumenindevami,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:11   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:16   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 2:54   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:16   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:43   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar,halkinbasbakanitokatta
5/8/2015 0:56   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:56   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:56   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:56   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 2:59   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:56   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:56   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:01   akp,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:03   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:04   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:04   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar,pinokyokemal,oyunuboz
5/8/2015 0:05   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:05   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:05   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:05   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:05   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:05   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:06   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:06   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:06   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:06   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:06   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:07   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:07   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:07   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:07   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:08   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:08   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:08   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:08   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:09   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:08   ak,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:08   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:08   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:08   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:09   akp,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:09   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:09   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:09   ogretmenatamaicin13mayistaankarada,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:09   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:09   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:09   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:09   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:09   ogretmenatamaicin13mayistaankarada,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:10   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:12   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:13   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:14   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar,pinokyokemal,oyunuboz
5/8/2015 0:15   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:15   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:15   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:16   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:16   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:16   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:16   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:16   ak,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:17   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:17   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:17   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:17   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5/8/2015 0:17   ak,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
```

I use this function to split each hashtag and add them a new data set. After it creates a table for them and put them into barplot.

```
t.plot=function (histogram){
  library(splitstackshape)
  histogram=cSplit(histogram, 'hashtag_text', ',', 'long')
  histogram=table(histogram$hashtag_text)
  barplot(histogram[order(histogram,decreasing=T)], width=1,main="Hashatag Frequency",xlab="Hahstags",ylab="Frequency")
  } 
t.plot(AKP.Slogans)
```

The result for 100 data is nice but for all data set it creates something really weird. How can I  create something the first picture. I can able chose ten of the most repeated hashtags.
I checked the other questions and I couldn't find the answer for it or I didn't understand how implement them into my problem.

Example for the first 100 rows
[image: Example for 100 rows]

Example for the all data set
[image: Example for all data set]

Thanks,

Comment: Try replacing `histogram[order(histogram,decreasing=T)]` with `head(histogram[order(histogram,decreasing=T)], 10)` to select the top 10.

Comment: Hi Gregor, do you know that how can I assign each label to each bar? As you can see that the names are not predefined !

Comment: Hi Gregor, I guess that I  need to work on cex.names parameter :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your function with `[1:10]` inside barplot:

```
t.plot=function (histogram){
  library(splitstackshape)
  histogram=cSplit(histogram, 'hashtag_text', ',', 'long')
  histogram=table(histogram$hashtag_text)
  barplot(histogram[order(histogram,decreasing=T)][1:10], width=1,main="Hashatag Frequency",xlab="Hahstags",ylab="Frequency")
histogram[order(histogram,decreasing=T)][1:10] # to get the Htgs
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert, do you know that how can I assign each label to each bar? As you can see that the names are not predefined !

Comment: Hi Robert, I guess that I  need to work on cex.names parameter :) Thanks

Comment: The names are the  most frequent `hashtag_text`. You can modified the labels using barplot argument, i.e. `names.arg = paste("Haststag",1:10),las=2`

Comment: it gives names like these: hashtag1,...,hashtag10 and it didn't give the names of the most 10 repated hashtags.